# Returning out of a function the results of an observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a function that I need to return an observable as it is being subscribed to elsewhere, but because my function is making a request asynchronously and then trying to return that data as an observable it is breaking.

An example of how it looks currently:

```
function userObservable() {
   const select = 'select * from users';

   this.db.query(select).subscribe(users => {
      // apply some logic and filter to users here

      // function just returns users as an observable
      return asObservable(users);
   });
}

function subscribeFunction() {
  userObservable().subscribe(users => {
     // do whatever
  });
}
```

but basically this is breaking because it seems like it's trying to subscribe in `subscribeFunction()` before the `userObservable()` function has returned the observable. Am I missing something in the way to implement this? Can I make it wait to ensure the first function is returning properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you subscribe to an observable it can only return a subscription and no longer be able to return observable

You can however use operators like map/filter to transform filter your user object and return it

```
  return this.db.query(select).pipe(map(users => {
      // apply some logic and filter to users here
      // function just returns users as an observable
      users=user.filter(........)
      return users
   }));
```

Comment: So using pipe instead of subscribe I can still access the values given from the initial observable?

Comment: yep that's how rxjs programming should be. We don't often subscribe until real execution is needed. We use different operators to compose transform data first.